# DataGridview cell not expending in WinForms Application C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a simple datagridview contain two columns .
I want to add text from textbox by pressing a button to column1 cell but it show only one text not the other and first one text replace the second one .

I want to add text from textbox to column1 cell as much as I want by pressing a button .

as in image showed

[image]

```
      this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode =
         DataGridViewTriState.True;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = 
     DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;

        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text + 
      Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: Looks like your code does exactly what you wrote. If you want more you will need to write more. Your question is very unclear.

Comment: do you mean to add another row with the given text when the button pressed?

Comment: No .For example I write hellow and press button the world hellow should be in column1 cell,then write c# or any else so it should to append  in cell

Comment: If you want to add rows to an unbound `DataGridView` you can simply use `Add` method of `Rows` collection, for example:     `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text);`

Answer (score 0):

Then you should try something like this:

```
        string tmp = "";
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode =
     DataGridViewTriState.True;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode =
     DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;

        tmp += textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine;

        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = tmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

doing slight change will help you to achieve the expected result

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value += textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine;
```

or

Read your cell data and append your new data and then replace the cell value

```
        this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode =
 DataGridViewTriState.True;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode =
     DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        var tmp = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value;
        tmp += textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine;

        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = tmp;
```